# Singleton can always be reflected(Reflection even enum)

Tags: java, reflection, enums, singleton

I have this simple enum that serves as a Singleton provider for an `Object` type object

```
package package2;

public enum SingletonEnum {

    INSTANCE;
    private Object obj = new Object();

    public Object getObject() {
        return obj;
    }
}
```

And i have this Sample main that reflects the field instance, modify the field by assigning a new object

```
package package2;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class Sample2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Object obj = SingletonEnum.INSTANCE.getObject();
    System.out.println(obj.hashCode());

    try {
        Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("package2.SingletonEnum");
        Field[] fields = clazz.getDeclaredFields();

        for (Field field : fields) {

            if (field.getType().equals(Object.class)) {

                field.setAccessible(true);
                field.set(SingletonEnum.INSTANCE, new Object());
            }
        }
    } 
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

        System.out.println(SingletonEnum.INSTANCE.getObject().hashCode());
    }
}
```

the output is

```
1554514352

2112239710
```

two different hashcodes where displayed, and I assume that two references were made. how come this possible? I thought enum Singletons are the only way to make Singleton "Singleton" and cannot be reflected, so this only means that only `SecurityManager` can prohibit all reflections. so my question is.. "WHAT" is the most safest way to prohibit an instantiation of a Singleton object?

Comment: It’s unclear what you are asking. `SingletonEnum.INSTANCE` *is* a singleton. This does not imply that it is immutable. Further, the instantiation of the other object does not happen when you modify the singleton’s field, it already happened before that, when you performed `new Object()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Singleton means there can only be one instance of the class. This is true for `SingletonEnum`. It does not mean that the instance is immutable. You are changing the `obj` member of the singleton which results in different hashCodes.
What you can do in this case is to define the object final, so it cannot be changed, though it must be initialized.

```
public enum SingletonEnum {

    INSTANCE;
    private final Object obj = new Object();

    public Object getObject() {
        return obj;
    }
}
```

Comment: Since the OP uses `.setAccessible(true)`, declaring the field `final` doesn’t help.

Comment: sorry and thank you, i've been obsess with Java reflection and the full security of Singleton..  i didn't notice im starting to forget the whole idea of Singleton and immutability/mutability of field members :(.. sorry. my mistake.. :(,